# Apple Privacy: How do I check if a version of an sdk I am using in my app uses a privacy impacting sdk?

Tags: ios, privacy-manifest

I am assuming that even if the app i am using is not listed in the ios list of privacy impacting sdks, if they use a privacy impacting sdk in their sdk, then my app will be required to get the privacy manifest for that privacy impacting sdk: the rule must (logically!) be transitive.

So far apple has not sent any email about the app needing to provide that for any of our sdks. but i am worried that maybe apple has not done the check for us yet, and by the time they do , we will be near deadline to submit an app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple began sending emails on March 13, 2024.

1. Submission to launch the app
2. Submission to use external TestFlight

In my experience, if there is a PrivacyManifest problem in the above situation, an e-mail was sent within 5 minutes.
(You can see that you will receive an e-mail almost at the same time as you submit it.)

The best way is to submit it to an external TestFlight while changing the build.