How to validate a PrivacyManifest.xcprivacy file is correct?
Apple is requiring iOS apps to include a PrivacyManifest.xcprivacy file starting on May 1, 2024.
Is there any way (other than submitting a new app version to Apple) to validate this file is correct? Is there a way Xcode can validate the file?
Ideally we could validate the file is formatted correctly before creating a new release. I haven't found any way to ensure we are doing this correctly other than getting this file into a new release and hoping Apple doesn't reject it.

The most efficient way to describe the data collected by your app or third-party SDK is by utilizing the Privacy Report In Xcode 15, you can easily generate a privacy report by performing an Archive build and then clicking the ‘Generate Privacy Report’ button.

I believe that the generate privacy report only reports on the NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes key, not on the NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes key, which is likely what the OP is looking for.

Please refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163463/apple-privacy-how-do-i-check-if-a-version-of-an-sdk-i-am-using-in-my-app-uses-a

Apple has already begun issuing notices regarding the implementation of this policy in iOS apps. Starting May 1, 2024, compliance will become mandatory for passing the App Store review process.
The most efficient way to describe the data collected by your app or third-party SDK is by utilizing the Privacy Report In Xcode 15, you can easily generate a privacy report by performing an Archive build and then clicking the ‘Generate Privacy Report’ button.
For more information about adding Apple privacy checklist to MAUI app, you can refer to Adding Apple Privacy Manifest Support to .NET iOS & .NET MAUI apps
.


I found you can verify the Privacy.xcprivacy is formatted correctly by attempting to open it with Xcode 15. Unless Xcode can open it, the file is not formatted correctly.
In my case I was using some XML provided by a third party which was not formatted correctly and through some trial and error of editing the file and re-opening in Xcode I could validate the format was correct once Xcode displayed the tags in a table similar to the Info.plist
